# Why output of the list is different? Python code

Tags: python

I can't understand while comparing between two codes.  output of `a` is 7 and `b` is 5, which is correct. But 2nd code, why does `another_list` show `['egg', 'rice', 'milk', 'bread', 'butter', 'chicken', 'pasta']` in the output? `print(another_list)` should show `['egg', 'rice', 'milk', 'bread', 'butter', 'chicken']` only, because I have commented out the line `another_list = shopping_list`.

```
a = 5
b = a
a += 2
print(a)
print(b)
print()
 
shopping_list = ["egg",
                 "rice",
                 "milk",
                 "bread",
                 "butter",
                 "chicken"]
another_list = shopping_list
shopping_list += ["pasta"]
print(shopping_list)
######another_list = shopping_list
print(another_list)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. How do I clone or copy it to prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-how-do-i-clone-or-copy-it-to-prevent)

Comment: It is because you are copying the reference. A trick is another_list = shopping_list[:]

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the elements of the list explicit. Otherwise you just create a second reference for the same data.

another_list = shopping_list.copy()